# How can I control the fonts in the Ogrekit find panel in TeXShop

Tags: texshop, find

I'm using TeXShop 4.57 with the Ogrekit find panel on a Mojave Mac.  The other day my find panel began display as in this pic:[image]

This is disconcerting.  I would like the same font in both panels, but I can find no preference item to adjust. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. But in my version (4.57) the size in both windows is the same. There have been a flurry of changes recently, and this was one small thing that changed, so make sure you're up to date.  One thing to try might be to change back to the Apple panel, quit TeXShop and then switch again to the Ogre panel.

Comment: Thanks Alan.  I tried that, didn't work.  Then I deleted all the TeXShop-related files in ~/Library, restarted, didn't work.  Finally I deleted everything (saving my templates) and reinstalled TeXShop.  That worked.  But the font size I now have is in between what you see in the two windows.  Go figure.  I wish it was adjustable because I like the small font, but I can't find anything in the TexShop.plist that seems to work.

Comment: As of this evening, I'm seeing this same problem. I'm running version 4.58.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently reported the issue to the maintainers of TeXShop and OgreKit (Richard Koch and Isao Sonobe) who have now solved the problem.

Changes introduced in version 2.1.10 of OgreKit had the following unintended consequence: A text snippet copy-pasted from some other source into the "Replace" field of the OgreKit panel would *retain the original format* (font, size, color, background color...), as shown in the question above. New text snippets would overwrite the previous style, so there was no way to fix the format stably and consistently.

The "Find" field was not affected: All text pasted into that field was *normalized* to the default format, as usual.

In the newly released **version 2.1.12 of OgreKit**, the "Replace" field behaves like the "Find" field in that text gets *normalized* to the default font, size, color etc. (The new default is `Menlo, regular, 18pt`.)
**TeXShop 4.79**, released today, includes the capabilities of OgreKit 2.1.12. Users can select their desired font for the panel.

From the [change log](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/changes_3.html):

> In addition, the font and font size used in the Find and Replace fields of the panel can be changed and the changes will be remembered even if TeXShop is quit and restarted. To modify these values, open the OgreKit Find Panel and then select the TeXShop menu `/Source/Font/Show Fonts`. The standard Font panel will open, allowing you to select a font and size. Do this for each field.

A user *wishing to revert to the previous behavior* of the "Replace" field and enable custom text formatting (as opposed to normalization) should check the box labelled "With styles" in the OgreKit panel.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Really glad to see this annoying issue resolved!

Answer (score 3):

Update to TeXShop 4.79!!! Then open the Ogrekit Find Panel (you need to set it as the default Find method in the Find Panel section on the Source tab of TeXShop->Preferncess). Then open the Font selection panel (Source->Font->Show Fonts or Cmd-K), choose your font, size, etc., and press return. That sets the Find pane's font. Select the Replace pane and do the same thing there. The new version of the Ogrekit Find Panel now saves the chosen fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, too. At least in my case, the font and the font-size in the replace box are changed by copy and past. That is, the font of the box inherits the font of the text in clipboard. Therefore, to change the font in the box,

1. Copy texts written in a word processing software such as MS Word and Apple Pages using your preferred font, and
2. Paste it to the replace box.

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: This has been fixed in the Ogrekit Find Panel in TeXShop 4.79. Update!